# How to encode cyrillic text into URI

Tags: ruby, wordpress, ubuntu

I am inserting data into wordpress mysql database through linux terminal with ruby. When inserting post tags into wp_term table, i introduce the tag in "name" field and also i must introduce it into "slug" field. If the tag is in english, it could be written as it is into "slug", but if it's in russian into the slug must be introduced something like %d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82

how to translate russian words in this %d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82 on ruby ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *looks* like it's URI-encoded.  URI-encoded utf8? Maybe.

If you provided the example of the russian text that translates into that, someone could try to figure out what it was exactly.

I am no WordPress expert, but it seems unfortunate that WordPress requires URI-encoded content in the db.

But if that's what it really is, try:

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape(utf_russian_text)

# eg
CGI.escape("Хаж ут дычэрунт")
```

Does that give you what WordPress seems to want?